# Does 广安话 have 翘舌音?

Tags: topolect

四川话很少有翘舌音，除了自贡、郫县有一些说法之外，真的很难找到四川话的翘舌音。

《广安方言与民俗词典》记了几个：

> 【che(-)n】?伸“she(-)n”的音变。指舒展开。“扯伸”，又说“拉伸”，指拉直。例：把衣服扯伸。

> 【cha(v)】?叉“cha(-)”的音变。指分开、张开。

> 【ché】?坼“chè”的音变。指物体表面或内部出现了裂缝。

这些大概是错的，不过没有证据。

广安话有翘舌音吗？

Comment: @user3306356：Welcome to this place, due to some chinese-learning foreigners, it would be nice if you can speak English mixed with Chinese.

Comment: No, Cantonese doesn't have 翘舌 or 捲舌. Here is a list of Cantonese phonology: https://zh-yue.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B2%B5%E8%AA%9E%E9%9F%B3%E7%B3%BB

Comment: I'm asking about 四川的 Sichuan's 广安 Guang'An 方言 Topolect - I'm not sure why you're telling me about Cantonese....

Comment: This question doesn't seem "Learning" but "Studying".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

广安属于巴蜀地区，广安话更接近于重庆话
和普通话区别的话就是语音语调不同，
广安话平翘舌不分，很多口语很具有地方特色

Comment: Hi SG Pro, not everyone in this forum is able to read Chinese. In general it's better to write answers in English so that it can be of help to more people.

Comment: The question is in Chinese, something called "Google Translate" might help you.